# Cloud platform for CI Test Automation Lab setup with Windows 10 or 7 OS

Tags: automated-testing, jenkins, continuous-integration

We have an on-premise test automation lab where we monitor all our applications (Web Applications and Web Services) through CI Jenkins jobs. Machines in the lab have either Windows 10 or Windows 7 OS.

Now, we would like to move our lab to the cloud platform and monitor applications from cloud instances. I did some research on AWS, Microsoft Azure and Google Cloud.

Both AWS and Google Cloud does not allow creating instances with Windows 10, 8 or 7. They only allow Windows servers.

But Azure does allow creating Windows 10 VMs. Also, Jenkins has a plugin for Azure to run the Azure VMs as Jenkins slave. So we are planning to do a PoC with Azure.

Which is the best cloud platform to setup Jenkins CI test automation machines?

Note: We need to integrate the instances with bitbucket, Logstash and On-Premise maven repository.